# Plasma 5.5.5 NetworkManagement Widget won't load the QML file

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04, kde, qml

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 using Plasma 5.5.5 and Qt version 5.5.1. I was running kernel 5.5.3 and upon upgrade to 5.5.4 the plasma widget for network management seemed to break. So I downgraded to the old kernel to see if that would fix the issue but no dice. I still have internet access (as I was able to post this question) but when I left click on the network widget I get the following message:

[image: Widget Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have searched this site and others with no success.

I have also tried removing and re-adding the widget from the panel so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downgrade to previous version of libkf5networkmanagerqt6

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libkf5networkmanagerqt6=5.18.0-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: One other thing though, why would this break the widget?